# unable to fit with GaussianNB - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.utils._pprint'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, naivebayes, pprint

When trying to run the `.fit` method of `GaussianNB`, I receive the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.utils._pprint'
```

I am able to cross validate:

```
cv_result = cross_val_score(GaussianNB(), X_train, y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring,n_jobs=njobs)
```

However the following doesn't work:

```
NB = GaussianNB()
NB.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I am currently on an Anaconda Jupyter notebook and using the following version

```
jupyter-client==5.3.1
jupyter-console==6.0.0
jupyter-core==4.5.0

scikit-learn==0.21.3
```

Any idea on what is causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

That command works fine on scikit-learn version 0.21.3 for me. It's likely that your ipython and related modules are installed in a different environment than scikit-learn. You should be able to test this by making a script and executing it with python. If that works, but it doesn't work running in ipython console or jupyter notebooks, try reinstalling ipython, jupyter and scikit-learn with anaconda/pip.

To be specific, I believe that your error is due to `NB.fit` returning `self`. This makes the jupyter notebook trying to display the `NB` object via the `__repr__` method, which in turn relies on `sklearn.utils._pprint`. A quick fix would be to change

```
NB.fit(x,y)
```

to

```
NB = NB.fit(x,y)
```

Comment: Nice guess, it wasn't the case unfortunately. I had to reboot my system and once I restarted the notebook everything was working properly.